# 'mongo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Path not working

Tags: mongodb, command-line, path, environment-variables

I installed mongodb.  I added "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin" to the "Path" System Environment variables.  (also tried with "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\")  Closed all command prompts.  Started a new one and still get the error message.  If I go the path in the command line, then run "mongo", it works.

What do I need to do to get the Path to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why this was not working for me.  In the tutorials, it says to close any command prompts you have open.  I did that.  The issue is that I am using ComEmu, which even if I closed all the command prompt tabs in it, was still pulling in the old PATH values.  (Tested this via "echo %PATH%".)  To fix this, I just right clicked on ComEmu in the toolbar and closed it.  On next open, it was pulling in the updated values and "mongo" worked.